# Closing the listening socket after a fork()

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

A common server socket pattern on Linux/UNIX systems is to listen on a socket, accept a connection, and then `fork()` to process the connection.

So, it seems that after you `accept()` and `fork()`, once you're inside the child process, you will have inherited the listening file descriptor of the parent process.  I've read that at this point, you need to close the listening socket file descriptor from within the child process.

My question is, why?  Is this simply to reduce the reference count of the listening socket?  Or is it so that the child process itself will not be used by the OS as a candidate for routing incoming connections?  If it's the latter, I'm a bit confused for two reasons:

(A) What tells the OS that a certain process is a candidate for accepting connections on a certain file descriptor?  Is it the fact that the process has called `accept()`?  Or is it the fact that the process has called `listen()`?

(B) If it's the fact that the process has called `listen()`, don't we have a race condition here?  What if this happens:

1. Parent process listens on socket S.
2. Incoming connection goes to Parent Process.
3. Parent Process forks a child, child has a copy of socket S
4. *BEFORE* the child is able to call `close(S)`, a *second* incoming connection goes to Child Process.
5. Child Process never calls `accept()` (because it's not supposed to), so the incoming connection gets dropped

What prevents the above condition from happening?  And more generally, why should a child process close the listening socket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linux queues up pending connections. A call to `accept`, from either the parent or child process, will poll that queue.

Not closing the socket in the child process is a resource leak, but not much else. The parent will still grab all the incoming connections, because it's the only one that calls `accept`, but if the parent exits, the socket will still exist because it's open on the child, even if the child never uses it.

Comment: A common reason for the parent to exit is to restart after a software update. If a child kept the socket open, the new server instance wouldn't be able to start up properly.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that there is a different type of race condition: the new, updated process trying to listen before a child of the old process had a chance to stop listening? Wouldn't it make sense to add a parameter to `fork()` to atomically close some sockets? As a workaround, servers could wait for all children having signalled that they closed the socket before exiting for a restart.

Comment: @JoachimWagner A new process would not be able to open a new socket to the same port while the old process is using it.

Comment: Yes and the new process may be the restart of a server after an update. We want the restart to succeed but it can be blocked by a recently created child process that hasn't yet received enough CPU time to have closed the socket. Granted this is unlikely even on a busy server as the restart will also be slowed down but the likelihood would increase a lot if the user the server switches to to drop privileges is restricted to a subset of CPUs, e.g. via cgroups.

Answer (score 2):

The incoming connection will be 'delivered' to which ever process is calling `accept()`. After you forked before closing the file descriptor you could accept the connection in both processes.

So as long as you never accept any connections in the child thread and the parent is continuing to accept the connections everything would work fine.

But if you plan to never accept connections in your child process, why would you want to keep resources for the socket in this process?

The interesting question would be what happens if both processes call `accept()` on the socket. I could not find definite information on this at the moment. What I could find is, that you can be sure, that every connection is only delivered to only one of these processes.

Comment: "*what happens if both processes call accept() on the socket.*" one of both processes will `accept()` the connection in an unspecified manner.

Comment: "*unspecified manner.*" in my previous comment will say that it is "*unspecified*" which process will get `accept()` the connection.

Comment: @alk Luckily, calling `accept()` from both processes is well defined. It has been used for decades by the Apache server. One of the process will get the connection. The other will sit tight. Of course, if two connections arrive _simultaneously_, then both processes are likely going to be awaken with nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

In the `socket()` manual, a paragraph says:

> `SOCK_CLOEXEC`
> Set  the  close-on-exec (`FD_CLOEXEC`) flag on the new file descriptor.  See the description of the `O_CLOEXEC` flag in `open(2)` for
> reasons why this may be useful.

Unfortunately, that doesn't do anything when you call `fork()`, it's only for when you call `execv()` and other similar functions. Anyway, reading the info in the `open()` function manual we see:

> `O_CLOEXEC` (since Linux 2.6.23)
> Enable the close-on-exec flag for the new file descriptor.  Specifying this  flag  permits  a  program  to avoid additional `fcntl(2)` `F_SETFD` operations to set the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag.
>
> Note  that  the  use  of  this  flag is essential in some multithreaded programs, because using a separate `fcntl(2)` `F_SETFD` operation to set the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag does not suffice to avoid race conditions where  one thread  opens a file descriptor and attempts to set its close-on-exec flag using `fcntl(2)` at the same time as another thread does a `fork(2)` plus `execve(2)`.  Depending on the order of execution, the race  may  lead to  the  file  descriptor  returned  by `open()` being unintentionally leaked to the program executed by the child process created by `fork(2)`.  (This kind of race is in principle possible for any  system  call  that creates  a  file  descriptor  whose close-on-exec flag should be set, and various other Linux system calls provide an equivalent of the `O_CLOEXEC` flag to deal with this problem.)

Okay so what does all of that mean?

The idea is very simple. If you leave a file descriptor open when you call `execve()`, you give the child process access to that file descriptor and thus it may be given access to data that it should not have access to.

When you create a service which `fork()`s and then executes code, that code often starts by dropping rights (i.e. the main apache2 service runs as root, but all the spawned `fork()` actually run as the `httpd` or `www` user—it is important for the main process to be root in order to open ports 80 and 443, any port under 1024, actually). Now, if a hacker is somehow able to gain control of that child process, they at least won't have access to that file descriptor if closed very early on. This is much safer.

On the other hand, my apache2 example works differently: it first opens a socket and binds it to port 80, 443, etc. and then creates children with `fork()` and each child calls `accept()` (which by default blocks). The first incoming connection will wake up one of the children by returning from the `accept()` call. So I guess that one is not that risky after all. It will even keep that connection open and call `accept()` again, up to the max. defined in your settings (something like 100 by default, depends on the OS you use). After max. `accept()` calls, that child process exits and the server creates a new instance. This is to make sure that the memory footprint doesn't grow too much.

So in your case, it may not be that important. However, if a hacker takes over your process, they could accept other connections and handle them with their canny version of your server... something to thing about. If your service is internal (only runs on your Intranet), then the danger is lesser (although from what I read, most thieves in companies are employees working there...)

Answer (score 0):

A child process inherits all files descriptors from its parent. A child process should close all listening sockets to avoid conflicts with its parent.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The asker wants to know why it's necessary to close all file descriptors and what can happen if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

The child process won't be listening on the socket unless accept() is called, in which case incoming connections can go to either process.

Comment: At least in Linux it's not really any process that `listen()`s but the OS.